# UITableViewCell from Cocoa Touch to Monotouch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'd like to use one of this two controls that are written in Objective C

- https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell
- https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell

There are some way to use my UITableView with one of those UITableViewCell?

Comment: Neither of these appear to be particularly long or complex.  Converting them from Obj-C to C# would be a good way to get some more experience with MonoTouch.

Comment: I've tried but take a bit of time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a xamarin.ios binding for the objective-c library. You can see how to do this [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries).

There is a tool available from Xamarin called [Objective Sharpie](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/objective_sharpie) which will give you a great starting point!

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html) is a walkthrough to create a static library in Xcode

Comment: but that one it's not a library. I must compile in XCode to generated a library? But good to know Objective Sharpie ;)

Comment: Yes you would need to create a static library containing the classes you wish to use then bind that library.